# 'docker ps' output formatting: list only names of running containers

Tags: bash, docker

`docker ps --format "table {{.Names}}"` output `NAMES` in first row:

```
root@docker-2gb-blr1-01:~# docker ps --format "table {{.Names}}"
NAMES
enr
osticket
osticket_db
...
```

`docker inspect --format '{{.Name}}' $(docker ps -q)`

prints `/`in the beginning of container name:

```
root@docker-2gb-blr1-01:~# docker inspect --format '{{.Name}}' $(docker ps -q)"
/enr
/osticket
/osticket_db
```

I want to list only names of running containers, without header or slash in beginning. Please share options how to do this.

Answer (score 215, accepted):

Try removing the `table` part from your `--format` argument, such as:

```
docker ps --format '{{.Names}}'
```

It should give you a simple list of container names with no table heading

Comment: how to query --> Container ID

Comment: for me only docker ps -a --format '{{.Names}}' works

Comment: @Vignesh_A docker ps -q to get the container ID

Comment: check this out:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50667371/docker-ps-output-formatting-list-only-names-of-running-containers/62336512#62336512

Comment: for ID's, can use,  docker ps --format '{{.ID}}'  ... the parameter between the braces is essentially the column short name used in docker ps output

Comment: Puzzled with the plural ``Names`` as opposed to ``Name``, surely a container has one name just like it has one ``ID``, and many ``Ports``!

Answer (score 144):

Here is how we query the other columns with `docker ps`.

Names:

```
docker ps --format '{{.Names}}'
```

ID:

```
docker ps --format '{{.ID}}'
```

Image:

```
docker ps --format '{{.Image}}'
```

Command:

```
docker ps --format '{{.Command}}'
```

Created:

```
docker ps --format '{{.RunningFor}}'
```

Status:

```
docker ps --format '{{.Status}}'
```

Ports:

```
docker ps --format '{{.Ports}}'
```

More information can be found [here.](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/ps/#formatting)

Comment: This is a kind of a cool answer :)

Answer (score 123):

Just a combination command, it is prettified with `table`.

```
$ docker ps --format "table {{.Image}}\t{{.Ports}}\t{{.Names}}"

IMAGE               PORTS                NAMES
nginx               0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp   nginx
```

In addition you can add it to `.docker/config.json` file that will allow you to customize the output of your `docker ps` command.

add to `~/.docker/config.json`:

```
{
  "psFormat": "table {{.ID}}\\t{{.Image}}\\t{{.Status}}\\t{{.Names}}"
}
```

Comment: Detailed documentation can be found [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/ps/#formatting)

Comment: Can be done without `table` e.g. `docker ps --format '{{.ID}}\t{{.Names}}'`

Comment: @ChrisHalcrow Yes, but using `table` keeps your columns clean and readable..

Comment: Or you can go all the way `docker container list --format 'table {{.ID}}\t{{.Names}}\t{{.Image}}\t{{.RunningFor}}\t{{.Status}}\t{{.Networks}}\t{{.Ports}}' | awk 'NR<2{print $0;next}{print $0 | "sort --key=2"}' | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="[[:space:]][[:space:]]+"} gsub("0.0.0.0:", "", $7) gsub(",?:::[^,]+", "", $7) gsub(" , "," ",$7) sub(", $", "", $7) sub(".*/.*/", "", $3) sub("minutes","m",$4) sub("minutes","m",$5) sub("hours","h",$4) sub("hours","h",$5) sub("ago","",$4) {printf("%-15s%-22s%-38s%-16s%-22s%-21s%s\n",$1" ",$2" ",$3" ",$4" ",$5" ",$6" ",$7)}'`

Answer (score 6):

> docker ps --format "\nDocker Details \nID:{{.ID}} \nNames: {{.Names}} \nSize: {{.Size}} "

looks like

[image]

Ref : https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/ps/#formatting

Answer (score 0):

For a clean and simple overview, I've placed this in my ~/.bashrc file:

```bash
function F_DOCKER_CONTAINERS() {
    local V_IFS=$IFS; local V_LINE=""
    IFS=$'\n'
    local V_OUT=""
    for V_STATUS in 'Up' 'Running' 'Restarting' 'Created' 'Paused' 'Exited' 'Stopped' 'Dead'; do
        V_OUT=""
        local V_LINE=""
        for V_LINE in $( docker ps -a --format "{{.Names}} {{.Status}}" | grep " ${V_STATUS}" ); do
            V_LINE=$( echo -n "${V_LINE}" | cut -d' ' -f1 )
            V_OUT="${V_OUT}\n${V_LINE}"
        done
        if [[ "$V_OUT" != "" ]]; then
            echo -e "\n\033[036m${V_STATUS}\033[0m${V_OUT}"
        fi
    done
    echo
    IFS=$V_IFS
}
alias docker-containers=F_DOCKER_CONTAINERS
```

Restart bash and just run `docker-containers`