# Export docker command result to CSV

Tags: docker

Export docker command result to a CSV file

For example, Result for the query `docker ps` should be stored in a CSV file.

Answer (score 1):

Well, is this a question, feature suggestion or what?

What docker command do you refer?

Any way, we can use `--format` to export a container list for example:

```bash
docker container ls --no-trunc -a --format='"{{.Names}}","{{.Image}}","{{.Ports}}","{{.Status}}"' >> my_docker_containers.csv
```

Where:

1. `docker container ls`: lists docker containers
2. `--no-trunc`: do not cut any informations
3. `-a` list all containers
4. `--format`: custom output

---

**Docker docs reference:**

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/ps/#examples

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/ps/#format

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/container_ls

**Stackoverflow reference:**

['docker ps' output formatting: list only names of running containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50667371/docker-ps-output-formatting-list-only-names-of-running-containers)

Comment: I've posted a similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75556906/12034580). Upvote to undelete it